# How to sort json data and display in a tableView as alphabetical order

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I'm implementing an app where i need to show a tableView. tableView needs to dispaly json data and have alphabetical search on the right side by clicking on any letter it needs to show data starting with that letter. I've implemented the vertical alphabet search and when user clicks on any letter it takes user to that particular section. But the problem is my json data is not getting sorted.

Here is my code for this. // Here exhibitorArray contains all the info to populate data in tableView.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"serverData" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [serverData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
NSLog(@"Sorted Array:%@",sortedArray);
```

Comment: You need to show at least ONE element of your array (or structure of `serverData`), and give us the key on which the array has to be sorted.

Comment: i could not understand your point can you please elaborate it

Comment: What's `serverData`? What does it looks like?

Comment: Can you print and give as your array values?

Comment: serverData is an array from backend which has to be sorted in alphabetical order and displayed in table view

Comment: 2017-08-04 18:18:17.109 DankPass[7320:165833] Server Data is:(
    Lamborghini,
    Jergens,
    InStyle,
    HSBC,
    Heineken,
    Hartford,
    GMAC,
    Geico,
    Fanta,
    Famous,
    FedEx,
    Ferrari,
    Forbes,
    eBay,
    Enbridge,
    Dentyne,
    Daewoo,
    Disney,
    Darden,
    Compaq,
    Camel,
    BlackBerry,
    Adidas,
    "Fluid system",
    Crowdfunding,
    "Ice Stupa",
    "Artificial glacier",
    loboGo,
    bibo,
    "Big Bazar",
    "New Brand",
    "Main Brand Name"
)     Here is the array

Comment: It's just an array of `NSString` then, so the `sortDescriptorWithKey:@"serverData"` won't work. I would have expected an error though on running.

Comment: i got the solution for my question                                                   
 **********sortedArray = [serverData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];  ********  the above code is working perfectly

Comment: now my question is when i tap on an alphabet like (when i tap on R letter) then it has to be moved to particular strings in the list ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *unsortedStrings = @[@"Lamborghini", @"Lamborghini", @"InStyle",@"HSBC",@"Heineken"];
NSLog (@"unsorted = %@",unsortedStrings);

NSArray *sortedStrings =[unsortedStrings sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

NSLog (@"sorted = %@",sortedStrings);
```

unsorted = (
    Lamborghini,
    Lamborghini,
    InStyle,
    HSBC,
    Heineken
)

sorted = (
    HSBC,
    Heineken,
    InStyle,
    Lamborghini,
    Lamborghini
)

Comment: now my question is when i tap on an alphabet like (when i tap on R) then it has to be moved to particular strings in the list ????

Comment: NSIndexSet *indexes = [sortedStrings indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *string, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [string hasPrefix:@"L"];
    }];                    and scroll you table to -> [indexes firstIndex]

Comment: do i have to write this code for every letter, (i mean for all 26 letters) ???

Comment: just find taped later and pass that late in this syntax and you get an index for that latter and scroll your table on that index.

Comment: i dint get you. Can you please elaborate it.....

Comment: how to write code for 26 letters